# How to display objects with data array in a Listview

Tags: java, android, listview

there is the following objects:

```
public class Course {
    private static int courseID = 0; 
    private String courseTitle; 
    private ArrayList<Assignment> assignments;
    private Course(String title, ArrayList<Assignment> assns)
    {
        courseTitle = title;
        assignments = assns;
        courseID++;
    }
    //returns a Course instant with random assignment values
    static public Course generateRandomCourse()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int assignmentNo = rnd.nextInt(5);
        ArrayList<Assignment> tempAssns = new ArrayList<Assignment>();
        for(int i=0; i < assignmentNo; i++)
            tempAssns.add(Assignment.generateRandomAssignment());
        return new Course("Course " + courseID, tempAssns);
    }
    public String getCourseTitle() {return courseTitle;}
    public ArrayList<Assignment> getAssignments() {return assignments;}
}
```

Course contains Assignment objects:

```
public class Assignment {
    private static int assID = 0; //static ID increments with every new
    private String assignmentTitle; //title of assignment
    private int assignmentGrade; //grade of assignment
    //private constructor. Increments ID.
    private Assignment(String title, int grade)
    {
        assignmentTitle = title;
        assignmentGrade = grade;
        assID++;
    }
    //returns an Assignment instance with random values
    static public Assignment generateRandomAssignment()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        String tempTitle = "Assignment " + assID;
        int tempGrade = rnd.nextInt(100) + 1;
        return new Assignment(tempTitle, tempGrade);
    }
    public String getAssignmentTitle() {return assignmentTitle; }
    public int getAssignmentGrade() {return assignmentGrade;}
}
```

The data must be displayed in a list view as:

[image]

I am following this tutorial:https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_list_view.htm.
Following it, the activity has an array of strings, creates an adapter and  links it to a Listwiew:

```
String[] mobileArray = {"Android","IPhone","WindowsMobile","Blackberry",
  "WebOS","Ubuntu","Windows7","Max OS X"};

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
     R.layout.activity_listview, mobileArray);

listView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mobile_list);
  listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The xml file contains:

```
   <ListView
      android:id="@+id/mobile_list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
   </ListView>
```

The activity_listview.xml file contains:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

How to get Listview from:
`ArrayList<Course>courses = new ArrayList<Course>()`?
Is a vertical layout within the listview needed?

---

Update:
Possible layout file course_row_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/coureTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/assignments"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>   
</LinearLayout>
```

possible assignment layout file assignment_row_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/assignmentTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cassignmentGrade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>        
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use custom adapter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin I am unsure how to mange the ArrayList that are part of the object. I updated the post with an attempt at the layout files, but I am lost with ListAdapter.

Comment: Just look for customAdapter in the internet, there are many good tutorials out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Course will be header type and Assignment will be section type of row in **ListView** . Then you can show the list in **ListView**. For your implementation help you can see this simple implementation--- http://stacktips.com/tutorials/android/listview-with-section-header-in-android